# Как в Delphi подключиться к CloudFlare с TLS v1.3?

Tags: delphi, tls, cloudflare

Работаю в Delphi XE8 Indy 10

```
HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
  HTTPClient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTPClient);
  (HTTPClient.IOHandler AS TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'root.pem';
  (HTTPClient.IOHandler AS TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.CertFile := 'cert.pem';
  (HTTPClient.IOHandler AS TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'key.pem';
  (HTTPClient.IOHandler AS TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  (HTTPClient.IOHandler AS TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  Result := HTTPClient.Get('https://www.example.com/');
finally
  FreeAndNil(HTTPClient);
end;
```

> Error connecting with SSL. error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Прочел, что CloudFlare использует TLS v1.3, но у в Delphi такой версии нет. Подскажите что можно сделать?

**UPD**

Попробовал так, но та же ошибка.

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function _GetSSLVersions(): TIdSSLVersions;
var
  I: TIdSSLVersion;
begin
  Result := [];
  for I := Low(TIdSSLVersion) to High(TIdSSLVersion) do
  begin
    Include(Result, I);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTPClient: TidHTTP;
  VIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  try
    VIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTPClient);
    try
      VIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := _GetSSLVersions;
      VIOHandler.SSLOptions.CipherList := 'ALL';
    finally

    end;
  finally

  end;
  HTTPClient.IOHandler := VIOHandler;
  SomeString := HTTPClient.Get(URL);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Клиентский сертификат обязателен? Если нет - попробуйте THTTPClient. Embarcadero рекомендует его для http[s] обмена вместо Indy

Comment: @kami всё работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы принудительно задали слишком старый метод шифрования (SSL v3), от которого уже практически все отказались ввиду его небезопасности, вот сервер и отклоняет соединение.

Я бы порекомендовал сконфигурировать клиента так, чтобы он предлагал серверу использовать любой доступный ему (клиенту) SSL/TLS метод (они с сервером об этом договариваются на этапе "рукопожатия"). Делается это так:

```
  function _GetSSLVersions: TIdSSLVersions;
  var
    I: TIdSSLVersion;
  begin
    Result := [];
    for I := Low(TIdSSLVersion) to High(TIdSSLVersion) do begin
      Include(Result, I);
    end;
  end;

...       
var
  VIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  VIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTPClient);
  VIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := _GetSSLVersions;
  VIOHandler.SSLOptions.CipherList := 'ALL';

  HTTPClient.IOHandler := VIOHandler; 

  Result := HTTPClient.Get('https://www.example.com/');
end;
```

Таким образом, мы разрешаем серверу выбрать любую версию SSL/TLS о которой мы знаем (максимальная в Indy пока что TLS v1.2) и любой алгоритм шифрования доступный в OpenSSL.

CloudFlare, помимо TLS v1.3, наверняка должен поддерживать и TLS v1.2 (это как минимум, а то и v1.1), поэтому Indy вполне сможет работать с этим сервисом.

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали, но не проходит.  Добавлю код в вопрос

Comment: @ArtGrek13 А ошибка-то какая?

Comment: такая же как в вопросе

Comment: @ArtGrek13 А url `https://www.example.com/`? Не должно оно ругаться на `sslv3`. Библиотеку openssl брали отсюда http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ ? Очень может быть что у вас openssl сильно устаревшая. Возьмите крайнюю версию http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2o-i386-win32.zip

Comment: да брал с того сайта, половину перепробовал

Comment: openssl 2017 года. Сейчас скачал openssl-1.0.2o-i386-win32.zip, скопировал две DLLки в папку с проектом, Ошибка та же

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Попробуйте тогда указать конкретно TLS 1.2: `VIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];`

Comment: Error connecting with SSL. error:1408F10B:SSL routines: SSL3_GET_RECORD: wrong version number

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Остаётся только обновить сам Indy из svn: http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/Indy10_5459.zip У меня в Delphi 10.3 приведенный код работает без каких-либо ошибок (на встроенной версии Indy).

Comment: Запустил в Delphi 10,2 сработало. Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 1):

С подсказки @kami написал такую функцию, все работает.

```
function GetFrom(URL: String): String;
var
  HTTPClient: THttpClient;
  HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
begin
    HTTPClient := THTTPClient.Create;
    try
      HttpResponse := HTTPClient.Get(URL);
      Result := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
    finally
      FreeAndNil(HTTPClient);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Со встроенным клиентом может возникнуть проблема, если вы попробуете запустить свою программу на устаревшей версии Windows XP и окажется что системные библиотеки не поддерживают нужные вам стандарты/алгоритмы шифрования. В то время как Indy через OpenSSL, на той же WinXP будет прекрасно работать (если использовать актуальную версию OpenSSL).

Comment: Я это понимаю, конкретно мне подходят оба варианта, так как я как промежуточный сервер делаю запросы дальше, и мое приложение будет работать только у меня